# Unity3D + Jenkins Configuration

Tags: jenkins, unity-game-engine, cloud, bitbucket

I'm using Unity3D, Jenkins and Bitbucket private repository. Jenkins is installed in cloud service. I want to automate buildings and probably run some tests in Jenkins before pushing to repository.

I have configured Jenkins properly to such step that it works when pushing some changes to repository, but this configuration doesn't contain configuration of Unity3D Build Plugin. In order to get Unity3D Build Plugin working properly you must configure it by providing the directory of your Unity3D Editor. Problem here is that Jenkins is installed in cloud service and Unity3D Editor on my computer. If you want to configure Unity3D Build Plugin you must provide it's .exe file location. So my question is that is it possible to tell Jenkins that is installed in cloud service that Unity3D installation directory is located at my computer? If yes how it is done?

Comment: Are you hosting Jenkins server on the clound and using your machine as node? If so it should be fairly simple to just point the install directory using the Unity3D plugin from jenkins, just set the install path in you node's settings.

Answer (score 0):

right now it's a limitation on the plugin. I hope to fix this. Open a bug in the issue tracker (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS) and let's move the conversation there!